# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: time_zone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I get this error while trying to submit my simple_form:

```
= simple_form_for(@profile, :url => profile_path, :method => :put) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .container
    = f.input :time_zone, :collection => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all, 
      :label_method => :to_s, :value_method => :name, :include_blank => false
  .actions
    = f.button :submit
```

I've put the `time_zone` in the accessible attributes:

```
class Profiles < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :time_zone

  belongs_to :user
end
```

and added the column to the table:

```
class AddTimeZoneToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :profiles, :time_zone, :string, :default => "UTC"
  end
end
```

and run the migration:

```
$rake db:migrate
==  AddTimeZoneToProfile: migrating ===========================================
-- add_column(:profiles, :time_zone, :string, {:default=>"UTC"})
   -> 0.0369s
==  AddTimeZoneToProfile: migrated (0.0370s) ==================================
```

for some reason I get the mass assignment error with it. Any clue on what's wrong here?

UPDATE: 
these are the parameters sent with the update request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"udKomXmmmOG+7Z4YKR03y9zMg58rnx1EXqE33a+6Shw=", "profile"=>{ "time_zone"=>"Stockholm"}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"profiles"}
```

thanks,

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Comment: $rails -v 
Rails 3.2.14

and ruby 

$ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

Comment: Try restarting your server

Comment: thanks, but restarting doesn't improve. I'm using WEBrick by the way.

Comment: Aside: `class Profiles` ? That should be singular: `class Profile`

Comment: Very well spotted @Zabba, for some reason I had two model files: `profile.rb` and `profiles.rb`, the first is the one I was supposed to have, the plural file was a mistake. I was adding the attr_accessible to the second. and of course it wouldn't work. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You should withdraw or answer your own question, assuming @dongiulio doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the commenters I figured that I had two model files: `profile.rb` and `profiles.rb`, the first is the one I was supposed to have, the plural file was a mistake. I was adding the `attr_accessible` to the second. and of course it wouldn't work.

stupid mistakes always generate stupid errors,

thanks.